# Книги по Python

Tags: python, книги

Решил заняться программированием. Выбрал "питон". Прошу, дайте названия, а лучше прямую ссылку на мануал. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Официальная документация](http://docs.python.org/) по языку Python. Ну и если знаний совсем нет, то ищите книгу Марка Лутца "Изучаем Python" -- одна из лучших (имхо).

Answer (score 4):

[Учебник Python 3.1](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_Python_3.1)

[Справочник по языку Python 3.1](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D1%83_Python_3.1)

[Погружение в Python 3](http://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%CF%EE%E3%F0%F3%E6%E5%ED%E8%E5_%E2_Python_3_%28%CF%E8%EB%E3%F0%E8%EC%29)

[Справочник по языку Python](http://notabenoid.com/book/5672/)

[Питон на русском](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/python/python-python.html.gz)

А вообще ищи в нэте книгу "Программирование на Python 3 Подробное руководство" Марк Саммерфилд.

Answer (score 3):

Марк Саммерфилд - "Программирование на Python3", по-моему лучшая из всех что видел.

Comment: Но это только, если важен Python 3, а вот мне, например, нужно django, а следовательно ветка 2.X

Comment: Там изменений не так уж и много(по крайней мере для начинающего питоновода), основа-то одна и та же. Да и список изменений можно в интернетах откопать.

Answer (score 2):

Также могу посоветовать книгу Дэвида Бизли "Python. Подробный справочник." Будет отличным дополнением к книге Лутца

Comment: Вот если бы у кого-то был этот самый Бизли в электронном виде было бы неплохо получить ссылку на него. Ибо в электронном виде найти не удалось, а в бумажном произведение сие стоит никак не меньше 350 грн

Answer (score 2):

По мне так - [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.org), если в ладах с английским.

Comment: Эту книгу оч хвалили на амазоне и кое-где в интернетах, но так и не понял, в чем её прикол..

Comment: ну если не в ладах, то вот перевод http://ru.diveintopython.org/toc.html

Comment: Не надо Пилгрима, там с первых страниц лезет всякая гадость. См. http://oppugn.us/posts/1272050135.html

Answer (score 1):

В электронной форме проще всего начать с wikibooks.org - python. Ну, а дальше оттуда по ссылкам.