# Как импортировать библиотеки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

К примеру, мне нужно импортировать библиотеку **main.py в index.py** и библиотеку **index.py в info.py**. **Как?**

Дерево проекта:

```
project_name
├── data
│   ├── info.py >>> second = 'World'
├── general
│   ├── main.py >>> first = 'Hello, '
└── index.py »»»concatenation = None
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.
├── data
│   ├── info.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── general
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
└── index.py
```

index.py:

```
import data.info
import general.main

print (general.main.first + data.info.second)
```

результат

```
user@desktop:~/python/test03$ python index.py 
Hello, World
```

Файлы `__init__.py` в папках `data` и `general` (в данном случае пустые) нужны для того, чтобы интерпретатор python воспринимал их как пакеты/модули.

Comment: Не подскажите, где можно о .pyc и __init__. почитать? На RU.

Comment: @KryfoAgapi на файлы `.pyc` - не обращайте внимания, они создаются сами, это байт-код (я их убрал из ответа). Я читал на официальном сайте `python.org`, но на EN, либо в любой нормальной книжке по питону.

Comment: @KryfoAgapi книги смотрите тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1579/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-python

Comment: >__init__  - тоже сами?

Comment: @KryfoAgapi, Вам нужно сделать файлы `__init__.py` в нужных папках самому. Их за Вас никто не сделает, т.к. только Вы знаете, должна ли являться данная папка пакетом модулей. О соответсвующих `.pyc` файлах позаботится сам python.

Comment: Будет работать и без `__init__.py`, хотя лучше их создать, чтобы неявные namespace пакеты не использовались.

Comment: @jfs, забавно, Вы правы. Просто я пользуюсь 2-м питоном, там без `__init__.py` не работает, а в 3-м работает.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы.